# Kotlin Crashs JSON

Tags: kotlin, gson

I have the body of the JSON returning to the following however it keeps crashing.

```
val body = response.body!!.string()
                         println(body)
                         val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                         val nowplayingFeed = gson.fromJson(body, NowPlayingJson::class.java)
```

It is meant to call

```
//NOW PLAYING DATA
class NowPlayingJson(val data: List<DataP>)

class DataP(val track: List<NowPlayingTrack>)

class NowPlayingTrack(val artist: String, val title: String, val imageurl: String, val type: String, val url:String)
```

But for some reason the `NowPlayingJson` is causing the file to crash.
When I set it to DataP

```
val nowplayingFeed = gson.fromJson(body, DataP::class.java)
```

It does not crash, but loads Null as it can't read the track due to it needs to read data first.

JSON

```
{"data":[{"track":{"artist":"COEO","title":"Cabrio Mango (Original Mix)","imageurl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/ad-system/AdStichr-Logo.png","url":"https://www.adstichr.com/","type":"S"}}]}
```

Comment: If you use `data class` instead for your classes you'll get a readable `toString`, so you can `println(nowplayingFeed)` and see something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample JSON the value of `track` is an Object. In `DataP` `track` is a List.

Should it be `class DataP(val track: NowPlayingTrack)` instead?

Comment: This is the correct answer. data has a list of tracks but a track is a simple object not a list. The error message is telling: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 20 path $.data[0].track"